# passing values to partial in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

Here is how I pass the values/variable to the partial:

```
<%= render "partials/banner", :locals => {:text_1 => t(:"main.home.banner_text_1"),
                                          :text_2 => t(:"main.home.banner_text_2") } %>
```

then in the partial:

```
 <%= text_1 %> <%= text_2 %>
```

but getting "undefined local variable or method text_1"

Where should I set the variable so it could be accesible from all views and layouts in my app?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be tempted to just put <%= t("main.home.banner_text_1") %> right in the partial -- can you get away with that? Or are they actually variable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have something that has to be displayed across all your views you can also create a application_helper method, Example: `banner('Text', 'Content')`

Try this:

Main page:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/test',
           :locals => {:text_1 => t(:'text_1'), :text_2 => t(:'text_2')}
%>
```

Partial:

```
<%= text_1 %> <%= text_2 %>
```

Comment: thanks adding ":partial =>" finally solved the problem. Wondering why it does not work without?
Anyway yes I need to have this displayed across all my views - can you provide more details how banner('text', 'content') helper method should look like? 
cheers

Answer (score 12):

I believe that Rails 3 has changed how you pass partial variables, to something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/test',
       :text_1 => t(:'text_1'), :text_2 => t(:'text_2') %>
```

Rails will parse that and since :text_1 is not a known key (like :collection or :as), it passes it to the partial itself.

You can access it via **text_1** or **text_2**