# Rails partials: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have this code in a partial called **"_form.html.erb" in "app/views/posts"**:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errores:</h2>   
        <ul>
            <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
<br />
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>
```

And I have two views with this code:

**"app/views/posts/new.html.erb"**

```
<h1>Nuevo post</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "Agregar Nuevo Post" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**"app/views/posts/edit.html.erb"**

```
<h1>Editar Post</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "Actualizar Post" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

What I want is the form to render in the views, but with the code I have shown to you I'm getting this error output in the server:

```
SyntaxError in Posts#new

Showing /home/levick/rubyblog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #10 raised:

/home/levick/rubyblog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #10):

7: </p>
8: <% end %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/levick/rubyblog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

The same with the edit view.

**My Question is:** What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your partial `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errores:</h2>   
        <ul>
            <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
<br />
  <%= f.label :content %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>
<%= f.submit @post.new_record? ? 'Nuevo Post' : 'Actualizar Post' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just forgot an `?` in the `submit` line, see the updated code above.

Comment: weird. try to remove the comma after the submit.

Comment: Hooray! it works! Now, I've seen you just changed this line:

<%= f.submit @post.new_record? ? 'Nuevo Post' : 'Actualizar Post' %>

in all the code, Could you explain me why did it work? what have you done exactly? (theorical part)

Comment: I've already accepted your answer, could you explain me why did that work?

Comment: First, @post will check if where it is coming from, if it is coming from an `new` action, they know that it is an new record and if so, will display `Nuevo Post`, else display `Actualizar Post`, all this in one line making use of ternary operator.

Comment: I get it! O.o You're Awesome!! Thank You. Didn't know about the ternary operator... Beautiful Solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the form variable outside of the partial. In both your new and edit pages you reuse the `f` variable even though it only exists inside the partial.

I would recommend you fix the error by moving the creation of the submit buttons inside the partial. Don't forget to also move the `<%- end %>` inside the partial too since you are finishing the form inside the partial.

Comment: But in my edit view The button says something else... How can I keep that behaviour?

Comment: You can pass in variable to the partial. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3222958/136584 for examples. Basically you are setting the :locals hash.

Comment: Could you please give me a practical example exactly for my case? I tried the examples in the question you link to and didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an <% end %> to close your <%= form_for %> block.